# Errors reinstalling MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, windows-7

*I am trying to re-install MySQL on Windows 7.*

While installing MySQL server initialization configuration Wizard,

when I hit the 'Exceute' button on the MySQL Server Instance Configuration screen it runs through 'Prepare configuration' and 'Write configuration file' OK but gives a red 'X' in the Start service button followed by the error message:

```
Could not start the service MySQL. Error 0:
```

I have tried uninstalling it then removing MySQL folder from program file and also removed all entries of from registry but still same problem is happening

How can I fix this?

Comment: **Possible duplicate** question: [could not start the service mysql.error 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132151/could-not-start-the-service-mysql-error-0) At the risk of asking the obvious: - A UAC issue (do you have admin rights)? - Did it work fine the first time you installed? - Did you try rebooting between attempts? Also [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Could+not+start+the+service%22+MySQL.+Error+0:') looks like it has many helpful suggestions:

Answer (score 0):

1) Your first stop should be the Windows Event Viewer

EXAMPLE: My Computer, , Manage, Windows Events

2) While you're in "My Computer, Manage" you should also see the MySQL service.
   Try turning it off and on.
   See if you get any meaningful error messages

3) For more info, look here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-log.html
- http://www.websiteadministrator.com.au/articles/install_guides/installing_mysql51_pg8.html